# Problems reading a 4GB SDHC but I can read a 8GB SDHC

Tags: dell, sd-card, xps, card-reader

I recently bought a Dell XPS L502X. The internal card reader had some trouble detecting cards but I was able to fix it using the workaround explained at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743

Now I can read my 8GB SDHC Card Class 10, but I am unable to detect a 4GB SDHC Class 4

I know that the sd is ok, because I can read it from my digital camera, and other computers too.

I post here, because I am interested in solve the problem using Ubuntu, but I have the same issue with the same memory on Windows too. (I have dual boot)

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone wishing to close or flag as off-topic: This shouldn't be done as the OP is asking about configuring the device or kernel to work within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having the same problems as you are on Windows in Ubuntu, this is appeares to be a hardware problem. I researched it and could find no one else with the same problem as you have, on either operating system. I would contact dell support about this one.

Comment: It is not the answer, because with a MacBook I have the same problem with the same memory. But I choose your answer as correct because, it was the only one.... and because that would be the same answer that i would give if someone ask.